# Split a list into sub-lists based on condition that there is a gap of size n

Tags: r, list, diff

I have a list of numbers that are increasing in nature (i.e. ever increasing).

```
alist <- c(1:20, 50:70, 210:235, 240:250)
```

The difference from one number to the next, is *n*.

I'd like to automatically split the list based on whether the difference between each item on the list is bigger than the threshold value of *n*.

For example, if the value of *n* > 20, for the particular list above it should split itself into 3 datasets.

Calling `which(diff(alist) >20)` tells me where I should "cut" the data up, but for the life of me I cannot figure out the next step... I might be missing something very simple here.

The result should ideally become a list of lists, or a table (I don't mind either):

```
[[1]]
 [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

[[2]]
 [1] 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65...

[[3]]
 [1] 210 211 212 213...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `cumsum` on a logical `vector` to create a group for `split`ting

```
unname(split(alist, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(alist) > 20))))
#[[1]]
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

#[[2]]
# [1] 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70

#[[3]]
# [1] 210 211 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 219 220 221 222 223 224 225 226 227 228 229 230 231 232 233 234 235 240 241 242 243 244 245 246 247 248
# [36] 249 250
```

---

If we need to use the `which` approach,

```
i1 <- which(diff(alist) >20)
Map(function(i,j) alist[i:j], c(1, i1 +1), c(i1, length(alist)))
```